# 'or' behaving strangely in python lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

i have this code, where I am reading some input from a file, sorting it, and summing every third element. If there is a amount of elements that are not divisible by 3, those last elements should be included in the summing.

```
import sys
from functools import reduce
items = int(sys.stdin.readline())

lista = sorted(list(map(int ,sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())), reverse=True)
overflow = items - (items % 3)

newval = reduce(lambda acc, a: acc+a[1] if a[0]+1 % 3 == 0 or a[0] > overflow  else acc, enumerate(lista))[1]
```

This works, for input like this:

```
6
400 100 200 350 300 250
```

But when I get a input that is not divisible by 3, like this:

```
8
400 100 200 350 300 250 50 25
```

Then this part of the code  "or a[0] > overflow" fails for some reason. The only thing it is suppossed to do, is to make sure that if there is trailing elements that is un-divisible by 3, then those should also be accumulated.

However, python throws this exception (for the last input)

```
File "shop.py", line 10, in <lambda>
newval = reduce(lambda acc, a: acc+a[1] if a[0]+1 % 3 == 0 or a[0] > 6 else acc,   enumerate(lista))[1]
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

I have no idea why I'm all the sudden doing something with a tuple, im performing the same operations as earlier, and only comparing ints to ints

Comment: This is pretty tricky code, particular the `reduce` call. What exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: `acc` looks like a tuple to me, considering the `enumerate()`. That said, I'd get rid of reduce in favor of a loop for the sake of anyone who is going to read this including your future self.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica The idea is is to sum the value of every third element in the list, and if the list has a length which is not divisible by 3, then the last one or two trailing elements should also be summed

Comment: @bereal yes, perhaps this is a bit convoluted, but the exercise is specifically for getting better at using functional functions.
Also, it works well for summing until it hits the "a[0] > overflow" case

Comment: @n00bster I woul group the values, and then sum them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872138/3141234 You can provide a fillvalue of `0` (so summing it won't effect the total)

Comment: @n00bster, you can do that using sum: `sum(lst[2::3] + lst[(len(lst) // 3 * 3):])`

Comment: @OlvinRoght nice! but it also throws exceptions for lists not divisible by 3

Comment: @n00bster, I've tested in console, no exceptions

Comment: also with the second testcase provided in the question?

Comment: @n00bster, [works with both](https://repl.it/@testerreplit/TinyOddballProcessor)